# MongoDB: Store array of models

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have declared following models:

**Banana**

```
var banana = new mongoose.Schema({
    src: {
        type: String,
        max: 1000,
        default: "yabadaba"
});
```

**User**

```
var user = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    bananas: [banana]
});
```

And I have problems inserting data to user collection. Here's the code:

```
var data = [{
    name: "Batman",
    bananas: [
        new banana({src: "nananana"}),
        new banana({src: "nana"})
    ]
}, {
    name: "Robin",
    bananas: [
        new banana({src: "meh"})
    ]
}];

for(var i=0, arrLen=data.length; i<arrLen; i++){
    var item = new User(data[i]);
    item.save();
}
```

And I it throws an error...

> CastError: Cast to Array failed for value "..." at user.bananas.
>   name: CastError,
>   kind: 'Array',
>   value: [Object],
>   path: user.bananas,
>   reason: [Object]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I did not need to store bananas to db, I created a workaround for this. If it was necessary to store bananas separately, then it is possible to reference them via object id.

So I removed Bananas model and modified User model as follows.

**User**

```
var user = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    bananas: [{
        src: {
            type: String,
            max: 1000,
            default: "yabadaba"
        }
    }]
});
```

I inserted values as follows:

```
var data = [{
    name: "Batman",
    bananas: [
        {src: "nananana"},
        {src: "nana")
    ]
}, {
    name: "Robin",
    bananas: [
        {src: "meh"}
    ]
}];

for(var i=0, arrLen=data.length; i<arrLen; i++){
    var item = new User(data[i]);
    item.save();
}
```

And it seems to be working.